# SQL query to get the data between two numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get data that matches the following query but it falls down on the last line using BETWEEN, where am I going wrong?

```
SELECT * FROM subscriptions 
WHERE status = 'active'
AND interval_type = 'day'
AND interval BETWEEN 1 AND 6
```

I'm getting an error code 1064

Comment: Can you provide the full error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`INTERVAL` is a MySQL reserved keyword, [see here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-I).  If you really have a column called `interval`, then you should escape it using backticks:

```
SELECT *
FROM subscriptions 
WHERE
    status = 'active' AND
    interval_type = 'day' AND
    `interval` BETWEEN 1 AND 6;
```

You should avoid using reserved keywords when naming your database objects.

Comment: Great thanks. I should've spotted that... I've taken over someone else's work so I would've been unlikely to call it that!